# AWS storage with one float

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-dynamodb

I have one key-value float as well as a much larger JSON-object that I want to store in the cloud for my iOS application. I want to use DynamoDB for the storage of my larger JSON-object, but I am wondering what tool I should use to store my key-value float. I need to be able to read / write to this key-value every second, whereas I only read / write from my JSON-object much less. I am thinking of using DyanamoDB for the JSON, and Redis for the key-value string that I would like to store, but because I am updating the value so often, it doesn't seem right -- I cannot cache the value. Is there any AWS tool that has faster latency than just storing everything on DynamoDB? Or should I just be storing everything on the same place (I am also looking to store user sessions, and I know Redis is also good at session storing)?

Answer (score 1):

Either dynamoDB using the DAX acceleration, or redis will offer sub-millisecond write times.

https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/

Comment: Is one of them better than the other at session storing?

Comment: 'Better' is a relative term. If you are going to use Dynamodb for other objects anyway, then I would lean towards using Dynamodb instead of redis just to reduce the # of moving parts - but I have used both for different purposes and both worked well.

Comment: Ok. Thank you E.J. Brennan!